# Is it a bug in MySQL covering index?

Tags: sql, mysql

Preparation:

```
CREATE TABLE project_sheets
(
    id            INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    project_id    INT NULL,
    path          JSON NULL,
    INDEX project_sheets_path_index(project_id, (CAST(path->'$' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY)))
) COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO test.project_sheets (project_id, path) VALUES (40, '[]');
```

Query with a bug(no rows returned)

```
SELECT * FROM test.project_sheets WHERE project_id = 40;
```

No bug(one row returned)

```
SELECT * FROM test.project_sheets IGNORE INDEX (project_sheets_path_index) WHERE project_id = 40;
```

If you add an element into array `path`, all will be OK.

Comment: A query on a table with a single row is unlikely to use an index.

Comment: This looks like a nasty bug in MySQL 8 (verified at least in MySQL 8.0.30). Good finding. As soon as you comment out the index all behavior comes back to normal.

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109333, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108659 looks like multi-valued indexes are buggy

Comment: A curious behavior. The documentation indicates: [13.1.15 CREATE INDEX Statement :: Multi-Valued Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) `:: Characteristics of Multi-Valued Indexes: ... Nullability and multi-valued indexes: If a multi-valued key part has an empty array, no entries are added to the index, and the data record is not accessible by an index scan. ...` and `Multi-valued indexes are subject to the limitations and restrictions listed here: ... A multi-valued index cannot be a covering index. ...`.

Comment: Try: `... INDEX \`project_sheets_path_index\`(\`project_id\`, (CAST(\`path\` -> '$[*]' AS CHAR(255) ARRAY))) ...`, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KC3Dil8B).

Comment: @wchiquito Good job! Will use it as a workaround. Tnx, again!